# how to get unique selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Unique selector is

```
#reg > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(1)
```

I want to use insertAfter() to add elements after that selector.

Comment: That's a **very** fragile selector. It's almost certainly worth adding in some kind of identifying markup so you can target maybe `$('#reg').find('.results tr.result')` instead, then you have much more freedom to change the HTML down the line if you need to. Coupling your JS to the HTML so tightly as this is likely to mean it needs rewriting

Comment: How often do you get a table with more than one `tbody` element? just `tbody` would do.  Also `:first` is generally a more readable option that nth-child(1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#reg > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(1)').after(yourdata)
```

You can do this but this is not a optimised jQuery selector...infact it might be the one of the worst performing. Check This http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

If i were you i would attach a class to each row and then maybe i could do like this:

```
$('.myrow').find('td').eq(index);
```

or you can use `document.querySelector('.myRow > td:nth-child(index)');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div/>').insertAfter('#reg > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(1)');
```